# differences between create-react-native-app and exp init

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I found that create-react-native-app is based on expo. but when using exp-cli, it is also based on Expo.

what are differences between create-react-native-app and exp init ?

Comment: create-react-native-app has been [replaced](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/glossary-of-terms/#create-react-native-app) with expo-cli as pointed out in one of the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer to this question is well documented in [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/workflow/create-react-native-app)

> ### Expo & "Create React Native App"
>
> Create React Native App lets you build a React Native app without any
>   build configuration. This may sound familiar to you because Expo does
>   this as well -- when you create a project with XDE or exp you don't
>   have to deal with Xcode or Android Studio configuration files, it just
>   works. This guide is intended to outline some of the key differences
>   between Expo and CRNA (create-react-native-app).
>
> **CRNA does not require you to have an Expo account**
>
> You can run create-react-native-app YourAppName and off you go. So what does not
>   having an account mean, and what would signing up and using XDE/exp
>   get you -- why do we require it with Expo? Having an Expo account
>   allows you to do the following:
>
> - Publish your project to a permanent URL, eg:`https://expo.io/@community/reactconf2017`.See Publishing on Expo for more information.
> - Build binaries for app / play store distribution. To do this with CRNA without using Expo,
>     you would need to run eject.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You said only differences are publishing and building app not functions. So I can use Expo's all modules in create react native. Is it right?

Comment: @HoYunLee first of all I didn't say it. I just shared a piece from the documentation. You should read it to get further more information. And yes you can use them all.

Answer (score 9):

Updated answer:

create-react-native-app was replaced by expo-cli.

https://docs.expo.io/workflow/glossary-of-terms/#create-react-native-app

Comment: Looks like expo-cli now it's just a layer for create-react-native-app.

Comment: ...and what about create-expo-app?

Answer (score 0):

There are advantages and disadvantages to either:

**React Native app advantage**:

You can add native modules written in Java/Objective-C

**React Native app disadvantage**:

Needs Android Studio and XCode to run the projects

**Expo advantages:**

Setting up a project is easy and can be done in minutes

Expo can build .apk and .ipa files

You do not need simulator to run your app.

**Expo disadvantages:**

You can't add native modules.

Your final app will bigger with expo init than with react native app init.

I suggest you read this:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo