# Difference between different ways to initiate a react-native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the difference between the following:

`npx react-native init MyNewProject`

and

`react-native init MyNewProject`

Expo projects can be initiated using the following:

The difference between the two methods can be found here ([differences between create-react-native-app and exp init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214823/differences-between-create-react-native-app-and-exp-init))

`create-react-native-app MyNewProject`

`expo init MyNewProject`

Answer (score 3):

`npx` is a command which allows you to run commands inside an `npm` package without having to install it. `npx react-native` and `react-native` are the same commands, except that to call `react-native` you'd have to install it using npm first.

```
npm install react-native
```

Comment: as [this reactnative.dev blog](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup#react-native-command-line-interface) states, "it recommends to use "npx react-native@latest init", If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues."   I don't know why?